# Number of ways to order a set of interdependent tasks

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I am aware that this question has been asked and answered before here.
([Combinatorics/Task Dependency](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569041/combinatorics-task-dependency))

I'd like some help understanding a part of the answer.

Consider the graph shown there:

```
  1
 / \
2   4
|   |
3   5  
 \ /
  6
 / \  
7   \
|    9
8   / 
 \ /
  10
```

The calculations given check out, but I can't understand why $4\choose2$ is the number of ways to order the tasks 2, 4, 3 and 5. Doesn't $4\choose2$ count all ways to choose the first two tasks to undertake, *including* the disallowed orderings (35)24 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${4\choose 2}$ cannot be interpreted as the number of ways to choose the first two tasks without restriction; this would be $4\cdot 3 = 4!/2!$. Instead, ${4 \choose 2}$ represents the number of ways we can choose, among the four positions, to place the two objects in the left chain (2,3).

This uniquely determines the ordering, since those objects must be ordered properly, the remaining spaces must be filled from the right chain (4,5), and they too must be ordered properly.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it :/ Can you explain further (especially the last line)?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury: Not sure what else to say in general, so let me provide an example. The 2-subset $\{1,3\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}$ corresponds to the ordering $(2,4,3,5)$ because we fill locations $1$ and $3$ with the objects 2 and 3; of course we must put 2 before 3. Then the remaining locations ($2$ and $4$) will be filled with the remaining objects (4 and 5)$; similarly we must put the 4 before the 5.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks! :)